# Smooth transition when divs is moved by another div being added ngAnimate and translate

Tags: angularjs, css, css-animations, ng-animate

I have two divs one on top of the other.

The top div is revealed with ngAnimate and pushes the second div down.

I want to use a translateY animation to reveal the top div because it looks good.

```
@keyframes enter_not_smooth {
  from {transform: translateY(-100px);} to {transform: translateX(0px);}
}

@keyframes leave_not_smooth {
  from {transform: translateY(0px);} to {transform: translateY(-100px);}
}
```

Problem: The bottom div does not move smoothly as the top div is revealed, it instead jumps to it's final position.

If I use a height animation to reveal the top div the bottom div moves smoothly as the top div is revealed.

```
@keyframes enter_smooth {
  from {height: 0px;} to {height: 100px;}
}

@keyframes leave_smooth {
  from {height: 100px;} to {height: 0px;}
}
```

Please see this jsfiddle if you need clarification https://jsfiddle.net/9bz4Lwxa/105/

Question: Is there any way I can achieve a smooth animation using the translateY property or another property that will achieve a similar reveal animation where the top div does not grow in height but is full sized and just pushes the bottom div out of the way?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tough one and something I've spent hours and hours and hours trying to accomplish. The only working solution I've come up with is really complicated and not worth all the extra code.

The problem is that when you use `transform` to animate an element, its bounding box remains static (seemingly behind the DOM scenes) and will not animate as to not affect any sibling elements. For reference, I'd read up on: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions

As an alternative to animating height/width/etc (because it causes repaints/reflows in the browser) I've resorted to using `transform` animations that simply feel better given the predicament.

I've created an example based on your fiddle here: 
https://jsfiddle.net/tommywhitehead/5q6wec92/1/

Note: It looks like you might be injecting `ngAnimate` in a non-traditional way so it's not reading the transition timing function (what places `.ng-enter` and `.ng-enter-active` at the right times) but I think this should give you the right idea.

I hope the big vendors can fix this somehow because this has been a huge issue for many devs.

Hope that helps!